# Parameter Format Not Correct in Apache Kafka

Tags: powershell

I'm following the [Apache Kafka Quickstart Guide](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart). I want to kill the leader node in my cluster, using the provided command 
`wmic process get processid,caption,commandline | find "java.exe" | find "server-1.properties"`
At this point I get this error `Find: Parameter Format Not Correct`.
I can't find any help over the Internet. Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you on a Windows machine?

Comment: Yes I am on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using Powershell to execute the command above. 
The `Find` command require the input to be a string, but in Powershell, things that are wrapped in quotations are evaluated for variable expansion or sub expressions. To make them a literal string, you can escape the quotations by a backticks.
So one solution would be:

```
WMIC process get processid,caption,commandline | find `"java`" | find `"server-1.properties`"
```

You can also use the `findstr` command instead of `find` which would look like:

```
WMIC process get processid,caption,commandline | findstr java | findstr server-1.properties
```

Now, you might ask why does Kafka's documentation have a wrong command?
The command isn't wrong. You can run the command in cmd just fine.